# How to get audio out of both front and rear jack sockets simultaneously?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I'd like to have sound output simultaneously from my PC's front and rear jack sockets.

This used to work fine with Ubuntu 12, but I now have Ubuntu 14.04 and it's one or the other.

So far I have tried changing the levels in alsamixer in the CLI, no joy.

However, I notice that in the alsamixer, the entry labelled, 'Headphone' is set to 00 and it cannot be changed, with or without a lead plugged in to the (front) jack socket.

Comment: Please post your solution as an "answer" to your question. You posted it as a comment, which makes it difficult for users to find if they have the same problem.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: Did you check [Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)

Comment: Bort, Dave - thanks.
Nimesh - I did check that page, but it refers to HDMI output.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JackDev Only the example is about HDMI output. Actually what it does is create a virtual device and provides output to all the available devices. I've used it for simultaneous output to USB speaker + 3.5mm Audio Jack speakers, but it should support any audio device recognized by system. I've not used alsamixer (probably the similar thing), will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the solution, I do not know how this worked:

1. Install gnome-alsamixer (I did it via the CLI).
2. In the gnome-alsamixer GUI, play about with the various mutes and sliders, then set them to what you want them to be.

Both the front and rear audio jacks now output sound (to my PC speakers and my hi-fi speakers).  Sweet!

The (other) weird thing is, when I plug the hi-fi (amp lead) into the PC's front audio jack, the PC speakers' volume goes up a bit.  If anyone can explain this, I would be interested.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Right - the solution seems to be: using the CLI,start **Alsamixer** (*the Gnome-alsamixer GUI doesn't seem to work for this*) and disable the **Auto-Mute**.  Sound comes out from front and rear jacks now.  Suh-weetah!  I can hear "I Am The Black Gold Of The Sun" by The Rotary Connection in glorious double stereo.